# Looped image video duration qual to mp3 track length

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an mp3 track.

How do I make a video that consist only from 1 image and that mp3 track playing on background, having video duration equal to this mp3 track length?

The correct answer should automatically calculate video duration based on mp3 track, so that I do not have to specify duration by myself.

Comment: Possibly duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887311/ffmpeg-1-image-1-audio-file-1-video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image -i audio.mp3 -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: -shortest  will do the opposite.

Comment: No. The loop makes the image loop indefinitely. So `shortest` stops the encode once the audio ends.

Comment: what about if i have multi images and want to loop images to match mp3 length